# how to set the sessionID in the request header using Ionic Angular

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

Here is my ionic code

```
let url ='http://localhost:8000/api/....';
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
let options = {headers: headers}
this.http.post(url, {id: id}, options).subscribe((data:any)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

I have done authentication but I need to send sessionID with each request. How do I add sessionID to my request header. NOTE: I'm using laravel at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpHeaders

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':  'application/json',
     sessionID: id
  })
};
```

More info in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http-send-data-to-server#add-headers